# Strange firefox error with Dojo 1.6.2

Tags: firefox, dojo

I have the following code written in Dojo. It works fine and as expected in all browsers except Firefox (25,26) The error from the console is: `typeError: this.getParent() is null` which is really not helpfull a lot.

The onclick event does't fire giving the above mentioned error.

Where could the problem be:

```
  var pMenu = new dijit.Menu({
        targetNodeIds: [ContainerNode]
    });

 var t = new dijit.MenuItem({
        label: "test",
        iconClass: "context_paste",
    });

dojo.connect(t, 'onclick', function(){alert("test")});
```

Comment: Is `ContainerNode` an ID or a variable? If it's the former, it should be a string. If it's the latter, what is its value?

Comment: So far any cases I've heard of DOM-related errors with older Dojo versions on FF 25+ are due to https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/17400, but if I'm not mistaken, a new 1.6 release with the fix hasn't been tagged yet.  You might want to try applying it yourself and see if it resolves your issue: https://github.com/dojo/dojo/commit/c67ea3e7a6463c8d5479b0c88007cd2c0c86443c

Comment: The containerNode is a variable containing a DIV element.

Comment: @KenFranqueiro I tried to use latest code from 1.6 branch in git that has this change applied but unfortunately it does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a fiddle and filled in the missing code and was not able to reproduce the error on Firefox 25. Some of the changes that I made were:

- Removed the trailing comma at the end of the `iconClass` line
- Place the menu item in the menu with `placeAt(pMenu)`
- Ran the code on load. I'm not sure you were doing this from the code provided.

http://jsfiddle.net/RichAyotte/okvp0hpu/

```
dojo.require('dijit.Menu');
dojo.require('dijit.MenuItem');

dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    var ContainerNode = document.getElementById('container');

    var pMenu = new dijit.Menu({
       targetNodeIds: [ContainerNode]
    });

    var t = new dijit.MenuItem({
        label: "test",
        iconClass: "context_paste"
    }).placeAt(pMenu);

    dojo.connect(t, 'onClick', function(){alert("test")});
});
```